# How to use both functions and scripts

Tags: matlab

I'm new to MATLAB and haven't got much programming experience, so I'm pretty stuck.

I need to create a file in which I'd have both functions (due to the GUI I have) and a script. I need to use the variables that I declare in the script in callbacks.

My program is an expert system. Firstly I declare rules as structure arrays, then I execute the algorithm. I don't understand how to call my rules which should be in a script-file inside my function-file.

**Update:**
I do understand that, however I've read lots of stuff and I still can't figure this out. I have file with the rules, which look like that:

```
rule(1).condition1='First condition';  
rule(1).cond1ask=1;  
rule(1).condition2='Second condition';  
rule(1).cond2ask=1;  
rule(1).conclusion='Conclusion';  
rule(1).endmarker=1;
```

and the file contains ±50 such declarations. Then I have a very simple GUI, which is supposed to run an algorithm when I hit the button. The question is: how do I combine the file with GUI functions and my algorithm and my file with the rules? How can I call the rules from the GUI file?

Here's the GUI code:

`% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton1.

    function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

    global rule

    % hObject    handle to pushbutton1 (see GCBO)

    % eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB

    % handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

    a1=rule(1).condition(1);

    a1`

Then I run the GUI file from my script-file, and though the interface loads okay, when I push the button I get error messages:

> Improper index matrix reference.
>
> Error in ES_21112012>pushbutton1_Callback (line 83)
>   a1=rule(1).condition(1);
>
> Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
>   feval(varargin{:});
>
> Error in ES_21112012 (line 43)
>   gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
>
> Error in
>   @(hObject,eventdata)ES_21112012('pushbutton1_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))
>
> Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

Comment: Your question is very vague, your description is too abstract. I suggest you visit [this link](http://www.mathworks.com/academia/student_center/tutorials/launchpad.html) for a proper introduction to MATLAB, attempt to take on the problem again, and ask a concrete question if you're stuck again.

Comment: I do understand that, however I've read lots of stuff and I still can't figure this out. I have file with the rules, which look like that:
`rule(1).condition1='First condition';
rule(1).cond1ask=1;
rule(1).condition2='Second condition';
rule(1).cond2ask=1;
rule(1).conclusion='Conclusion';
rule(1).endmarker=1;`
And the file contains ±50 such declarations. Then I have a very simple GUI, which is supposed to run an algorithm when I hit the button. 
The question - how do I combine the file with GUI functions and my algorithm and my file with the rules? How can I call the rules from the GUI file?

Comment: Do you have something already written in MATLAB? It would help a lot if you post the main parts of your code in your question.

Comment: Yeah, I've got some pieces of code. I've edited the post to make it easier. Thanks for your trouble, Eitan!

Comment: I think the _actual_ code is still missing. For instance, what is the code of your GUI file? What do you mean by "supposed to run an algorithm"? If you don't provide more details, your question cannot be answered really.

Comment: Added the code of the button callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your problem is that you dont have access to your variable 'rule' inside your callback function. It can be tricky to do this sometimes when writing GUIs.

One of the most general ways to achieve global access a variable when using GUIs is to use the setappdata function after you first define the variable. I'm confused by your description of your program, but wherever it is that you first define this 'rule' structure you can add this:

```
% rule = struct(); % Define your rule struct first
setappdata(0,  'myRules',  rule);
```

You can then retrieve this variable without having to somehow pass it to your callback functions as an argument by calling getappdata:

```
rule = getappdata(0,'myRules');
```

Note that this is not the only solution and may not be the best for your program but without fully understanding the logic of your program it's hard to give more specific advice.